# SwiftUI. How to change the leading inset of the List top separator?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Since iOS 16, SwiftUI automatically adjusts list row insets so the separator is aligned to the leading edge of the text.
[image: List row separators]
I need to change the leading inset of the List very top row separator like in Messages.app.

[image: Screenshot from Messages.app]

I have tried the `alignmentGuide(_:computeValue:)` modifier with no success.

Comment: what do you mean change it, how?

Comment: @devdchaudhary Since iOS 16, SwiftUI automatically adjusts list row insets so the separator is aligned to the leading edge of the text. I want to align the very top row separator to the leading edge of the text too (like in Messages.app).

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @liudasbar sadly no